# How to implement TF in Java?

Tags: java, information-retrieval

I have a document-term list in following format ( in a txt file). The total number of document is 1400. For example :

doc 1 : hello, I, hello, expense, daily (here doc 1 is a text file)
doc 2: Expense, hello ( here doc 2 is a text file)
.........

Now how can I implement TF in java ? TF is how many timer a term appear/total number of terms in a document

The code so far, It calculates how many times a term occur in a document

```js
public class termdoc {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        File file2 = new File("D:\\logs\\termdoc.txt");
        PrintWriter tdr = new PrintWriter(file2, "UTF-8");
        Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,Map>m1=new HashMap<>();
        String wrd;
        int unqwrd=0;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=1400;i++){
            Scanner tdsc=new Scanner(new File("D:\\logs\\AfterStem"+i+".txt"));
            while(tdsc.hasNext()){
              Integer docid=i;
              wrd=tdsc.next();
              Integer freq=m.get(wrd);
              m.put(wrd, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
              m1.put(docid,m);
       
           }
        tdr.println(m1);
        m.clear();
        m1.clear();
        tdsc.close();
        
    }
        //System.out.println(m.size() + " distinct words");
        tdr.close();
       
        
}
    
}
```

Comment: Choose better variable names, indent your code, respect the Java naming conventions, and tell what TF means, what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Please explain what TF is.

Comment: I think according to context TF means Text-Filtering ? how many times text occurs in documents... as mentioned in question.!

Comment: just edited the question with respect to tf

Answer (score 0):

You have the number of times each term appears in the document.

Sum all those values, and you have the total number of terms in the document.

Then divide the number of times a given term appears in the document by the computed sum, and you have the frequency.